# Displaying data from an XML file, on a listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, xmldataprovider

I have an xml file named Data.xml and it looks something like this

```
<Data>
  <NumberID>23423 </NumberID>
  <NumberID>34234 </NumberID>
  <NumberID>45435 </NumberID>
  <NumberID>67867 </NumberID>
</Data>
```

I want to display these numbers, on a ListBox control on my application. How can I bind this xml file to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XmlDataProvider:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Items" Source="Data.xml" XPath="Data/NumberID" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}" />
```

Comment: It works but now I have another problem. NumberID sometimes have some child elements, so the ListBox shows, the numbers, followed by the content of the child elements.

Comment: You could try (not tested) <ListPath ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items} XPath=text()}" />

Comment: No, that does not do what it should. Append text() to the XPath within the XmlDataProvider: <XmlDataProvider ... XPath="Data/NumberID/text()" /> That works.